# Test class Rest Webservice parameters

Tags: rest-api, webservices, unit-test

I´m having problems with url parameters (req.requestURI) in my test class.

This is my code.

REST CLASS:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Accounts/*')
global class StoreController {



   @HttpGet
    global static String getAccounts() {


        integer pageNumber=integer.valueof(RestContext.request.params.get('page'));
        string  ptime=RestContext.request.params.get('time');
        string  hash=RestContext.request.params.get('hash');

    }
```

REST TEST CLASS:

```
@isTest
private class StoreControllerTest {

    static testMethod void testGet() {


    //do request
    RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
    RestResponse res = new RestResponse();

    req.requestURI = 'https://dev-my-my.cs14.force.com/mine/services/apexrest/Accounts?page=0&time=1390296387&hash=1wer2547';  


    req.httpMethod = 'GET';
    RestContext.request = req;
    RestContext.response = res;

        String results = StoreController.getAccounts();

    }
}
```

When i run test class i get the error:

```
System.NullPointerException: Argument 1 cannot be null
```

for line :

```
integer pageNumber=integer.valueof(RestContext.request.params.get('page'));
```

Looks like parameters are not taken from url
'https://dev-my-my.cs14.force.com/mine/services/apexrest/Accounts?page=0&time=1390296387&hash=1wer2547'

when i run the test class.Please can you help me with this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Change your test class to use the [RestRequest.addParameter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_restrequest.htm) method. This method is used for setting parameters to be used by the webservice in a test.

You should also use a relative URL for the request URI value instead of hardcoding a fully qualified URL. I would also suggest adding some assertions to the test method.

```
@isTest
private class StoreControllerTest {

    static testMethod void testGet() {

        //do request
        RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();

        req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/Accounts';  
        req.addParameter('page', '0');
        req.addParameter('time', '1390296387');
        req.addParameter('hash', '1wer2547');

        req.httpMethod = 'GET';
        RestContext.request = req;
        RestContext.response = res;

        String results = StoreController.getAccounts();

    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer, that's hard to find elsewhere on Google, esp. example on using relative url and use of addParameter. +1

Comment: I've been spending 2 hard working days just to get this answer..you rock Mark..thanks a lot!